# Data is not being inserted. Where I am going wrong in php?

Tags: php

I have checked thoroughly that my database, table and column names are all correct. Still my data is not getting inserted.

Here is my PHP code:

```
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "thehealthsync";

        // Create connection
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        if(isset($_POST["t12"]))
            {
                $firstname = $_POST["t4"];
                $lastname = $_POST["t5"];
                $gender = $_POST["t6"];
                $pin = $_POST["t7"];
                $address = $_POST["t8"];
                $email = $_POST["t9"];
                $password = $_POST["t10"];
                $conpass = $_POST["t11"];
                if(!empty($firstname) && !empty($lastname) && !empty($gender) && !empty($pin) && !empty($address) && !empty($email) && !empty($password) && !empty($conpass))
                {
                    if($password == $conpass)
                    {
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO userdata (firstname, lastname, gender, pin, address, email, password)
                        VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$gender', '$pin', '$address', '$email', '$password')";
                    }
                    else{
                        echo 'Password did not match';
                    }
                }
                else{
                    echo 'Some fields are empty';
                }
            }
            $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: post your html form please

Comment: start debugging it. And show your post values

Comment: debug it by add code: die($sql); after your query. It for making sure if condition is passed and it will show your real query in browser.

Answer (score 1):

It is not inserted because you don't execute the query. After sql string

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO userdata (firstname, lastname, gender, pin, address, email, password)
                    VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$gender', '$pin', '$address', '$email', '$password')";
```

add

```
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You never send the query to the database, you only set a `$sql` variable. You'll have to call `mysqli_query` to actually execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

dude, put  `mysqli_query($sql)` under the `$sql` code